# how to get the coordinate of pinchgesture in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I am working on UIPinchGesture its working fine. I want to find the coordinate of image(x,y,width,height) when shrink and large every time. My code is:

-(IBAction) handlePinchGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender {

```
CGFloat factor = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *) sender scale];
CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:self.moveImageView];
NSLog(@"The Coordinate is:--->  x = %f y = %f", point.x, point.y);
if (factor > 1) {
```

moveImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(lastScaleFactor + (factor-1),
                                                         lastScaleFactor + (factor-1));
                    } else {
                        moveImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(lastScaleFactor * factor, 
                                                         lastScaleFactor * factor);

```
                    }

if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
    if (factor > 1) {
        lastScaleFactor += (factor-1);
    } else {
        lastScaleFactor *= factor;

        }       
    }
```

}

moveImageView is the object of UIIMageView. The coordinate of x and y are printed, but we need also the height and width.

this work fine, i want to find the current coordinate (x,y,width,height) of image after a scaling(shrinking and large) of image. Any one help me plz asap.

Thanks in advanced:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the exact state of an `UIImageView` at any exact state even during an animation, then you need to access the presentation layer. As the model layer is not updated during animation. This can be done like so -

```
UIImageView *i    = (UIImageView *)sender;
CAlayer *imgLayer = [i.layer presentationLayer];
```

This `imgLayer` has the exact co-ordinates, you need. including the size (width, height).

Comment: thanks for replying me: but please tell me where i put this code.

Comment: @pinku, you put this code in your pinch method. i.e. as the pinch is happening, if you want the exact this is how...

Comment: m putting this on pinch method; moveImageView    = (UIImageView )sender;
CAlayer *imgLayer = [moveImageView.layer presentationLayer];

Comment: i have post our pinch method. please help me.

Comment: it becomes crash like.. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPinchGestureRecognizer layer]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b27de0'

Comment: you need to include `core animation` framework. Without that these delegates are meaning less...

Comment: you need to add CORE ANIMATION!!!!! how much simpler do you want me to explain. You question framing too is very confusing & then all these... Try it out earnestly first...

Answer (score 1):

-(IBAction) handlePinchGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender {

```
NSLog(@"image.frame.sizeWidth111 %f",moveImageView.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@"image.frame.sizeHeight111 %f",moveImageView.frame.size.height);

CGFloat factor = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *) sender scale];
CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:self.moveImageView];

NSLog(@"The Coordinate is:--->  x = %f y = %f", point.x, point.y);
```

//if the current factor is greater 1 --> zoom in

```
if (factor > 1) {
                moveImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(lastScaleFactor + (factor-1),
                                                     lastScaleFactor + (factor-1));
                } else {
                    moveImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(lastScaleFactor * factor, 
                                                     lastScaleFactor * factor);

                    }

if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
    if (factor > 1) {
        lastScaleFactor += (factor-1);
    } else {
        lastScaleFactor *= factor;

        }       
    }   
NSLog(@"image.frame.sizeWidth222 %f",moveImageView.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@"image.frame.sizeHeight222 %f",moveImageView.frame.size.height);
```

}